# How to get the `next` element of `e.target`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` tag, which is then followed by a `label` tag. I am trying to get the value of the `label` after the `input` has been clicked. My trial was `e.target.next.val;` but that seems to be wrong. Any ideas how I could achieve that?

Comment: Please update your question with code and relevant HTML.

Comment: While code would help greatly. You can only use `.val` for inputs, etc. You probably want to use jQuery's `.text()`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to get the `innerHTML` of the `<label>` next to the `<input />` tag where the event was triggered. All you need to use is `.next()` and `.text()` or `.html()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").click(function (e) {
    // Using event.target.
    console.log($(e.target).next("label").text());
    // Using $(this).
    console.log($(this).next("label").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" />
<label>Click the button to access this text.</label>
```

Comment: @PatrickLüthi Can't find your answer. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, at all. In the DOM API you can always reach the "neighbor" element using `element.nextElementSibling`. You can read text from non-input-Elements using `element.textContent`.

In your code, simply replace my `document.getElementById('foo')` by `e.target`.

Here we go:

```js
const labelText = document.getElementById('foo').nextElementSibling.textContent;

console.log(labelText);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" />
<label for="foo">Labeltext here</label>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/phfmouea/)